# Bounds of variables in triple integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have to find the values of interchanged variable $x,y$ and $z$ in the following triple integrals: $\iiint_D xyz(\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{yz}+\sqrt{zx})dV$ when $D$ is a region bounded by $zx=1, yz=1,xy=1, x\geq0, y\geq0,z\geq0.$

I took $u=xy, v=yz$ and $w=xz$ to change the origin variables into new suitable ones. I am asking if the new bounds are correct? Am I on a right track?

$0\leq u\leq1, 0\leq v\leq1,0\leq w\leq1$

Comment: Yes. you are correct.

Comment: @Mathlover: Thanks!